# SSRS Last Week Monday and SUnday

Tags: reporting-services

I need the last week Monday and Sunday , say today is March 18th hence the SSRS expression
should return 
March 10th -Monday
March 16th -Sunday

I was able to get it using SQL

```
select dateadd(d,(2-datepart(dw, getdate())), dateadd(ww,-1,getdate()))



select dateadd(d,(1-datepart(dw, getdate())), getdate())
```

not sure how to get it done via SSRS expression

Answer (score 44, accepted):

SSRS VBA allows very similar expressions for date manipulation to Sql, the main difference being the use of the DateInterval enum. Without checking your expressions, it will convert to SSRS VBA as follows:

Last Monday:

```
=DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 2-WeekDay(Today), DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -7, Today))
```

Last Sunday:

```
=DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 1-WeekDay(Today), Today())
```

Comment: What about expression Last Saturday?

Comment: Saturday is 7 so use that number instead of the number used for the day above

Comment: How about finding last to last Monday

Comment: @JibinMathew Just wrap another `DateAdd(DateInterval.Week, -1, ...` around the last Monday expression

Answer (score 2):

To get Sunday from Last Week :
(Note: Last Week Sunday is different from Last Sunday).

```
=DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 1-WeekDay(Today), DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -7, Today))
```

To get Saturday from Last Week :

```
=DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 7-WeekDay(Today), DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -7, Today))
```

with Weekdays values as below:
1 - Sunday
2 - Monday
3 - Tuesday
4 - Wednesday
5 - Thursday
6 - Friday
7 - Saturday