# Date Parameters Defaults in SSRS

Tags: date, reporting-services, parameters

I am trying to work out to do the following.

I have two date parameters a start and end date.

What I want to default in the start date is the FIRST MONDAY of the PREVIOUS month from the day you run the report.

The End date I would want to default the day BEFORE the FIRST MONDAY of the CURRENT month the day you run the report.

So if I was running it today the first Monday of November was 03/11/14. The day before the first Monday for December is 30/11/14, so that would be the end date.
Another example if I run the report sometime in Jan next year - it will default to start date - 1/12/14 (first Monday in December) and the end date will be 4/1/15 (the day before the first monday in Jan)

Hope the above makes sense?

Comment: This should help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22471805/ssrs-last-week-monday-and-sunday

Comment: That's showing me first Monday of the week not the month - sorry I can't get my head around what I need to do to achieve what I'm after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a long IIF() expression to achieve your goal. Put the expressions below into your parameter default values.

FIRST MONDAY of the PREVIOUS month from today:

```
=IIF(Weekday(DateAdd("m", -1, DateSerial(Year(Now()), Month(Now()), 1)))=2,
DateAdd("m", -1, DateSerial(Year(Now()), Month(Now()), 1)),
DateAdd("d",9-Weekday(DateAdd("m", -1, DateSerial(Year(Now()), Month(Now()), 1))),DateAdd("m", -1, DateSerial(Year(Now()), Month(Now()), 1))))
```

The day BEFORE the FIRST MONDAY of the CURRENT month：

```
=IIF(Weekday(DateSerial(Year(Now()), Month(Now()), 1))=2,
DateAdd("d",-1,DateSerial(Year(Now()), Month(Now()), 1)),
DateAdd("d",8-Weekday(DateSerial(Year(Now()), Month(Now()), 1)),DateSerial(Year(Now()), Month(Now()), 1)))
```

The above expression has been tested. I can‘t share you screenshot currently due to low points.

Comment: I have no idea how to pick the bones out of that - but it WORKS!!!! 
Thank you so, so much.

Comment: Hi, I have run my report today - but it is coming up with the 9th of Feb as opposed to the 2nd of Feb for the start date and the 08th of March as opposed to 1st of March - why would that be?