# How to display Last week Sunday and last week Saturday in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2017

How to display Last week Sunday and last week Saturday from current date in SSRS  ?

In sql server we can find the last week Sunday and last week Saturday  from todays date(CurrentDate='19-02-2020') as

`select DATEADD(wk, -1, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0,getdate()), -1))-- for sunday`

`select DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, getdate()), -2) --for saturday`

So how we can write an default expression in the SSRS Parameters?

Comment: Have you tried using the `DateAdd`, `DateDiff`, and `Today` functions in SSRS? When you write an expression, there are examples included on the bottom half of the screen if you click on a function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SSRS Last Week Monday and SUnday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22471805/ssrs-last-week-monday-and-sunday)

Comment: Here the week start from Sunday to Saturday

Answer (score 2):

This assumes that the first day of the week is a Sunday, if you configuration is not like this then you will need to adjust the expressions to correct the offset

For Last Saturday use:

```
=DATEADD(DateInterval.Day, Weekday(Today()) * -1, Today())
```

For Last Sunday use:

```
=DATEADD(DateInterval.Day, (Weekday(Today()) -1) * -1, Today())
```

Comment: Yeah in this case the First day of week is Sunday and the week is from Sunday to saturday So the above code is as per this configuration.